# Textbook recommendation for Advanced Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What textbook would you recommend that covers higher order derivatives of composite functions, inverse functions?

I looked through Apostol, but he was too brief for me. I'm looking for an accessible text with lots of examples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608523/advanced-calculus-resource-for-multivariate-and-complex-calculus?rq=1 - also see comments.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Advanced+Calculus+book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so I might as well answer this question. I have used **Sean Dineen's "Functions of Two Variables"**. It's sort of like a primer with bite-sized chapters that don't get derailed into tangential topics and irrelevant (only marginally useful) exercises. I have read and done the exercises in the first $15$ chapters and was unable to solve maybe one or two problems meaning the exercises are there **only** to reinforce previously studied material and prepare you for what's to come. In a way, it's almost like a tutorial, but a rigorous one. It's an extremely efficient book and a very fast read. I loved it.

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get your wings soon enough! Book looks great, will start working through it asap.